# Using Tesseract to read dates from a small images

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a rather small set of images which contains dates. The size might be a problem, but I'd say that the quality is OK. I have followed [the guidelines](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) to provide the clearest image I can to the engine. After resizing, apply filters, lots of trial and error, etc. I came up with an image that is almost properly read. I put an example below:

[image: tesseract test]

Now, this is read as `“9 MAR 2021\n\x0c`. Not bad, but the first `2` is read as `"`. At this point I think I'm misusing part of the power of Tesseract. After all, I know what it should expect, i.e. something as `"%d %b %Y"`.

Is there a way to tell Tesseract that it should try to find the best match given this strong constraint? Providing this metadata to the engine should heavily facilitate the task. I have been reading the documentation, but I can't find the way to do this.

I'm using `pytesseract` on Tesseract 4.1. with Pytyon 3.9.

Comment: the guidelines you linked state "for 4.x version use dark text on light background", are you inverting the image you posted before processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the followings:

- [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)
- [When to apply - dilation or erosion](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#dilation-and-erosion)
- [Centering the image](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html)

Now if we center the image (by adding borders):

- [image]
- We up-sample the image without losing any pixel.

Second, we need to make the characters in the image bold to make the OCR result accurate.

- [image]

Now OCR:

```
29 MAR 2021
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("xsGBK.jpg")

# Center the image
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 50, 50, 50, 50, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Dilate
gry = cv2.dilate(gry, None, iterations=1)

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(gry))

# Display
cv2.imshow("", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```